# Azure Dataout spike for my WebApp

Tags: azure-web-app-service

Been running my site on Azure for 2 months with no big issues.  Today I notice a HUGE data spike in my DATAOUT.  Note that I don't have any big media files (nothing > 100k on the site) and do not have an FTP site in use.  I'm not even sure how anybody could transfer this much info if they wanted to.

A bit hard to read, but at 9:48am Eastern today the spike was 230 meg, while all other intervals are about 1 meg

I couldn't find any specific tools in Azure to help me track down what this spike is all about.  An IP address (I suspect it's one IP) would be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's really a strange Dataout spike. There are some ways you could try to trace down the spike.

1. If you have opened the **diagnostics logs** in App Service, you could search the related logs in Kudu at 9:48am.
   [image]
2. If you have an **application insight** service which maps the App Service, you could filter data to find the specific spike record during this time. For example, I have a Dataout spike at 3:22 PM.
   [image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't using Application Insights at the time of the data spike, therefore no information was captured.

Comment: If so, it's really difficult to reproduce your issue. You can monitor your web app later.